# non-default access to an elevated process from a non-elevated process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

sorry for bad english

Is it possible for a non-elevated process to get non-Default access rights(E.g. `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`) to an elevated process when they both have the same logon session id by changing the elevated-process security descriptor in the process explorer security tab?
i tried to change security descriptor of an elevated process  and selected  Full Access for the logon session SID.but still in the non-elevated process when i call `OpenProcess()` with the `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access right  it returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: Seems to *me*, that it would be a huge security hole if that was possible.

Comment: i used an elevated process explorer to change the security descriptor,why shoud not be possible?

Comment: of course this is possible. but you forget about mandatory label. you need set it to medium or low (untrusted) level for elevated process. after this you can open it from non-elevated. if your non elevated process have Medium integrity Level - you need set to medium or low in sd of elevated

Comment: @RbMm i changed the integrity level of the elevated process to  medium(same as non elevated one) and still can not OpenProcess()

Comment: @shbruzu - i personally can. need look for your elevated process SD and not elevated token

Comment: you also can instead change label level - change it access mask  - remove `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP` flag. after this also we can open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

begin from vista exist also [Mandatory Integrity Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648648(v=vs.85).aspx). elevated process have High Mandatory Label (*S-1-16-12288*) with `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_WRITE_UP` and `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP` mask. from another side not elevated process have Medium Mandatory Level (*S-1-16-8192*) in token. so when it try open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` which is part of generic read for process object - we usual fail do this from non-elevated process (medium level) for elevated process (high label and `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP`).

for let open with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` elevated process from not elevated - we need change elevated process mandatory label. or set it to medium or low, or remove `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP` flag. last option - the best for my look

for remove `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP` we can use next code:

```
// hProcess must have READ_CONTROL | WRITE_OWNER 
ULONG RemoveNoReadUp(HANDLE hProcess = NtCurrentProcess())
{
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;
    };

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 128;

    static volatile UCHAR guz = 0;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    ULONG err;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (GetKernelObjectSecurity(hProcess, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD, cb, &rcb))
        {
            BOOL bPresent, bDefault;
            PACL Acl;

            if (!GetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSD, &bPresent, &Acl, &bDefault))
            {
                return GetLastError();
            }

            if (bPresent)
            {
                if (DWORD AceCount = Acl->AceCount)
                {
                    union {
                        PVOID pv;
                        PBYTE pb;
                        PACE_HEADER pAH;
                        PSYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE pMLA;
                    };

                    pv = Acl + 1;
                    do 
                    {
                        if (pAH->AceType == SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE_TYPE)
                        {
                            if (pMLA->Mask & SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP)
                            {
                                pMLA->Mask &= ~SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP;

                                return SetKernelObjectSecurity(hProcess, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD) 
                                    ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
                            }
                        }
                    } while (pb += pAH->AceSize, --AceCount);
                }
            }
            return ERROR_NOT_FOUND;
        }

    } while ((err = GetLastError()) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

    return err;
}
```